# Use toggle buttons to update a record in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hopefully not too difficult question but I cannot figure this out and have been unable to find anything searching the forums.

I want to convert the output of my toggle boxes from 1,2,3,4,5 to the text each button displays.

Couldn't find any setting on the toggle boxes properties themselves so decided I would have to write a macro/vba to do it from the table but as it's quite new to me I am struggling on syntax.

I have tried doing this on the inbuilt data macro mainly, but also tried it via a query and vba and still couldn't figure it out.

[don't have any reputation yet so have not been allowed to post pics of my macro attmept]

please help! Any solution using vba, data macro or a query would be great

EDIT

To be specific rather than a message box I want to update field1 in my table "Major Equipment" based off the option group selection this is my latest attempt but still not sure how to reference the option group. Do I need to set grp equal to the option group and if so how? Is it something like forms!myform!optiongroup ?

```
 Option Compare Database

Function MyFunc(grp As OptionGroup)

Dim rcrdset As Recordset

set grp =
Set rcrdset = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Major Equipment", dbOpenDynaset)

Select Case grp.Value
  Case 1
    With rcrdset
    .AddNew
    ![Field1] = "Not Reviewed"
  Case 2
    .AddNew
    ![Field1] = "Reviewed"
  Case Else
    MsgBox "Error"
End Select

End Function
```

Also just realised since these toggle buttons will be updated by the user and so I probably need an update rather than addnew?

http://i59.tinypic.com/2ym8wet.jpg

Comment: Tehre is some learning required for that, and there is a lot of available Help.  By toggle box, do you mean radio buttons, or what?

Comment: Toggles boxes as described here.. http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/create-a-check-box-toggle-button-or-option-button-HP005188421.aspx (Wish I could post a pic instead)

Comment: You mean "toggle button"?

Comment: Yeah you are right apologies. I have them in a box of about 5 buttons which is where the confusion has come from

Comment: I gotta ask, because you never know what new feature they're going to slide in there ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons are part of an Option Group.  That is what you must reference.  Below is a [snippet from my net search](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access.formscoding/passing-option-group-valu/14397).

**From the `AfterUpdate()` event of your Option Group:**

```
Call MyFunc(Me.MyGroup)
```

**... which will use `Select Case` to evaluate:**

```
Function MyFunc(grp As OptionGroup)

Select case grp.Value
  Case 1
    MsgBox "Option value is 1."
  Case 2
    MsgBox "Option value is 2."
  Case Else
    MsgBox "Huh?"
End Select

End Function
```

If you are entirely new to VBA, there are a half-dozen things to learn here, but they will serve you well.  VBA provides a bit less-friendly-looking start than a macro, but I can tell you have more adventures ahead and I suggest you skip macros.  For most needs, VBA will serve you better; and it's much easier to trouble shoot or provide details when you need advice.

To convert this to a useful function, you will fill a string variable rather than raising a message box.  Then you can use the string variable to do something like run an update query.  Your latest edit suggests you will go for something like:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Major Equipment] " _
   & "SET Field1='" & strUserSelection & "'  " _
   & "WHERE MyID=" & lngThisRecord 
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

Your last edit proposes using a DAO recordset.  I think you might be fine with the humble `DoCmd`.  Less to learn.  You can hammer out a prototype of the query in good ol' Access; then switch to SQL View and paste the query into your VBA module.  Insert variables as seen above, taking care with the quote marks.  If it doesn't work, use `Debug.Print` to grab the value for `strSQL` and take that back to good ol' Access where you can poke at it into shape; use your findings to improve the VBA.

Comment: Had a go, but still haven't quite got it unfortunately. I put my code as an edit in the original post